# React native convert string to 12 hours format

Tags: react-native, momentjs

Code:

```
moment.utc('2000-01-01T15:40:00.000Z', "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z").local().format('hh:mma')
```

I am trying convert string to 12 hours format.expecting result is 15:40 pm.but It gives wrongly as 9:10pm.How to solve this issue?any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a utc date and then using `local` to convert that into local time zone so it will always add the offset into that, for example for India +5:30 etc, so remove local if you don't want to convert the date. If you want the output as 15:40 then you need to use format as: `format('HH:mma')` capital H not small h.

Use this:

```
moment.utc('2000-01-01T15:40:00.000Z', "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z").format('HH:mma');
```

Check the [DOC](http://momentjs.com/) for more details.

Check this output of this snippet:

```js
let a = moment.utc('2000-01-01T15:40:00.000Z', "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z").format('HH:mma');

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It will print **"15:40pm"**